# Error trying to install java on OS Monterey

Tags: java

In the first instance, I installed Rosetta with the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then, I going to install Java, in my case, **I need to download 11.0.1 (build 11.0.1+13)**, I used this link: https://jdk.java.net/archive/

In the search menu, I look for the library, select the library folder that is at the root, within the library I go to Java (folder) and open JavaVirtualMachines (folder), and paste the extracted file.

Until this point, all is ok, but, when I try to open Terminal and type `java -version`, I get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied" UserInfo {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: Permission denied}
```

I think that the file cannot be trusted. I go to **System Preferences** > **Security and Privacy** > **General** tab and select **Allow Anyway** and try again; I get the same error.

Does anyone have the same error? What solution did you find?

Comment: What has the installation of Rosetta to do with this, and why do you install the x86 version of Homebrew? What does `ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` show?

Comment: I would note that macports provides an arm version of openjdk11 (as well as many others) https://ports.macports.org/port/openjdk11/